# How to write every line of a text file into new files and name them according to its content?

Tags: text-processing, zsh, macos

I have have a text file with many lines like this:

```
Smith: ''Handbook of Everything.'' Fantasy Press, 2000.
Wilson: ''Unix for Dummies.'' Wiley, 1993.
```

I want to write every line into a new file. The new file should contain the whole line and should be named same to the line it contains.

```
Smith: ''Handbook of Everything.'' Fantasy Press, 2000.txt
Wilson: ''Unix for Dummies.'' Wiley, 1993.txt
```

How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ fname=$0 "txt"; print > fname; close(fname) }' file
```

Comment: @αғsнιη Duplicate lines - good point, missed this one. No golfing award for me today :(

Comment: @Fiximan these days people are looking for hats :  )

Answer (score 2):

If your textfile is called `textfile`, the following should do the job

```
while read -r x
do
    echo "$x" > "${x}txt"
done < textfile
```

Comment: Consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: And [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bash script as shown below. Replace `/tmp/textFile.txt` with the absolute path to your text file.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/tmp/textFile.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
        printf "%s\n" "$line" > /tmp/"$line"txt
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Why the `touch` part? Note that there's nothing bash-specific in that script. It's standard `sh` syntax.

Comment: Point taken. It's good to know this script is portable to other shells, and can be executed using zsh for example.